# PHP Removes End Zeros?

Tags: php

Say I have

```
$number = .20
```

When I go to run the script, PHP automatically removes the zero, leaving just .2. How can this be fixed?

I know that .2 and .20 are the same, but what I am using this number for, I need the zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only think I can think of which requires the trailing 0s is displaying the number. .20 can be printed as follows:

```
// The number to display
$n = .2;

// The number of decimal places
$places = 2;

// Print the number to the desired precision.
echo number_format($n, $places)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$num = "0.20";
echo "Num is:".$num;

//OR
$num = number_format(0.20, 2);
echo "Num is:".$num;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a string

```
$number = '.20';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could format the number using:

```
$num_decimal_places = 2; // This will give .20
$formatted = number_format($number, $num_decimal_places, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

.20 is a float literal.  After it's parsed, it's converted to [floating point](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).  You can format it with two decimals later with:

```
sprintf("%.2f\n", $number);
```

But if you're not using it as a number at all, Mike is right that you should just keep it as a string.

Comment: I used the one @erm410 said. The value changes, so that's why I can't use a string like Mike said.